# Missing data count with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with TimeSeries (all columns are casted to `float`) that are indexed with a DatetimeIndex (granularity/frequency is about 1 hour) for row and a MultiIndex for columns. There are missing data within the series (but no missing row, frequency is set). I would like to compute an acquisition performance (percentage) by month.

```
def mapMonth(x):
    return x.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

c = data.groupby(mapMonth).count()
```

The above code seems to count values ignoring `NaN` which is what I want. Now I would like to divide this aggregated DataFrame by the expected count.

```
n = pd.DataFrame(np.full((data.shape[0],), 1, dtype=float), index=data.index).groupby(groupby.mapMonth).sum()
```

It gives me expected data count by month, but I found this way very tricky.
Anyway I could not succeed dividing the DataFrame `c` by `n` using:

```
p = c.div(n, axis=0)
```

DataFrames look like:

```
networkkey      RTU                                                         
measurandkey    NO2
sitekey      41B001 41B004 41B006 41B008 41B011 41MEU1 41N043 41R001 41R002
channelid       280    27     38     55     59     86     103    122    168
2012-01-01        0    728    728      0    728    732    728    728    728
2012-02-01        0    679    678      0    680    686    681    681    679
2012-03-01        0    728    727      0    727    720    726    728    722
2012-04-01        0    705    698      0    702    710    699    705    701
2012-05-01        0    728    728      0    726    728    725    724    680
2012-06-01        0    703    700      0    701    710    705    705    705
2012-07-01        0    728    728      0    728    657    707    728    728

                0
2012-01-01  744.0
2012-02-01  696.0
2012-03-01  744.0
2012-04-01  720.0
2012-05-01  744.0
2012-06-01  720.0
2012-07-01  744.0
2012-08-01  744.0
2012-09-01  720.0
2012-10-01  744.0
2012-11-01  720.0
2012-12-01  744.0
```

I suspect the problem is because of the `MultiIndex`. Anyway I do not find this method straightforward.

Is there a cleaner/cleaver what to compute this aggregate with Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the `size` function which does not ignore `NaN`. Therefore the following code perform what I want in few lines:

```
# Group Data:
g = data.groupby(groupby.mapMonth)

# Compute Performance
c = g.count()
n = g.size()
d = c.div(n, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to your problem. : )